# *Highchart* Disable the legend item click

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a pie chart and want to disable the option hide the series when we click to the legend. I use:

```
events: {
                legendItemClick: function () {
                  return false
                }
              }
```

but it seems not working. How can I do that ?

Here is my jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9pj3kxr6/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For pie chart, each legend item is connected to the point/slice, so this event should be set on `point.events` level:

```
  plotOptions: {
    pie: {
      allowPointSelect: true,
      cursor: 'pointer',
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: false
      },
      showInLegend: true,
      point: {
        events: {
          legendItemClick: function() {
            return false;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

See demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9pj3kxr6/1/

Comment: thanks Pawel, it solved my problem