# Disable legend item click in a Highchart defined as JSON

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts

I need to disable the ability to click items in the legend in a HighChart. Normally I would use the following on a point or series as appropriate:

```
events: {
  legendItemClick: function() {
    return false;
}
```

However the page I'm working on requires the *entire HighChart* to be defined within a JSON object, for example:

```
{
  "chart": { "type":"column"},
  "xAxis": { "categories":[a, b, c, d] },
  "series": [{
    "name": "name",
    "data": [0,1,2,3]
  }]
}
```

Obviously I can't put a function within a JSON, so I'm struggling to find a way to disable legendItemClick.

I could override the site templates to build the chart in JS, and then I could solve my problem. But I've been requested to try to make it work within the current system.

I would welcome any suggestions.

EDIT: Added some clarity on why I can't use a function.

Comment: Check this URL: `http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/legend/enabled-false/` and this `https://stackoverflow.com/a/34337256/9775003`

Comment: Thanks - however the first link shows an example where the event function needs to be defined in order to return false, but I cannot include a function within a highchart defined within a JSON. The second link disables the legend entirely, which I'd prefer not to do.

Answer (score 0):

Using json data, update your series data as

```
data: [{
      name: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer',
      y: 56.33,
      legendActive:true, //attribute for legend, true means click will work 
    }, {
      name: 'Chrome',
      y: 24.03,
      sliced: true,
      selected: true,
      legendActive:false,
    }, {
      name: 'Firefox',
      y: 10.38,
      legendActive:false,
    }, {
      name: 'Safari',
      y: 4.77,
      legendActive:false,
    }, {
      name: 'Opera',
      y: 0.91,
      legendActive:false,
    }, {
      name: 'Proprietary or Undetectable',
      y: 0.2,
      legendActive:false,
    }]
```

Use function for legend click

```
 point: {
        events: {
          legendItemClick: function() {
            return this.legendActive;  //this is property from series data
          }
        }
   }
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Build the chart
  $('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
      plotBackgroundColor: null,
      plotBorderWidth: null,
      plotShadow: false,
      type: 'pie'
    },
    title: {
      text: 'Browser market shares January, 2015 to May, 2015'
    },
    tooltip: {
      pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
    },
    plotOptions: {
      pie: {
        allowPointSelect: true,
        cursor: 'pointer',
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: false
        },
        showInLegend: true,
        point: {
          events: {
            legendItemClick: function() {
              return this.legendActive;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    series: [{
      name: 'Brands',
      colorByPoint: true,
      data: [{
        name: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer',
        y: 56.33,
        legendActive: true,
      }, {
        name: 'Chrome',
        y: 24.03,
        sliced: true,
        selected: true,
        legendActive: false,
      }, {
        name: 'Firefox',
        y: 10.38,
        legendActive: false,
      }, {
        name: 'Safari',
        y: 4.77,
        legendActive: false,
      }, {
        name: 'Opera',
        y: 0.91,
        legendActive: false,
      }, {
        name: 'Proprietary or Undetectable',
        y: 0.2,
        legendActive: false,
      }]
    }]
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I think I may need to clarify my question, as it's not the data that's in a JSON but rather the chart definition. On the site I'm working on, a script looks for pre tags with a specific highcharts class, then parses the JSON within those pre tags to build a highchart (apparently the purpose of this is to avoid calling highcharts on every page template). What this means is that I can't include any functions at all within the highchart definition. In almost all cases this works fine, but I've run into a wall with the legend.

Comment: so your json contains `"chart"`,`xAxis` and `series`, you can add  `plotOptions` using setoptions dynamically using https://www.highcharts.com/docs/getting-started/how-to-set-options based on charts requirement.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It appears that I'm unable to get the name of the chart within the page framework (for some reason it's not in the Highcharts.charts array), so I can't pass any further options to it. I may have to give up and just re-do the chart in JS.